# How to pass only JSON object in post field in c# which then gets stored in mongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I have a POST method (c#) that inserts some data in MongoDB's collection. The type of the 'Data' field is 'object'. The model class for post request is below.

```
 public class Products{
         [required]
         public string Id {get; set;}
         [required]
         public object Data {get; set;}
         [required]
         public bool Valid {get; set;}
     }
```

So the issue is, I insert a json structure data in 'Data' field and it gets added too. However, when I enter a string type data like `Data = "Entering dummy data"`; This also gets added. Is there a way to avoid string getting added? Is there a datatype to insert only json type object. or any check be used for that?

Answer (score 0):

Validate the object data

```
JToken.Parse(data);
```

if an exception raises then it is not a proper JSON.

Comment: I tried using property type as `JsonObject Data` and that also worked.